# How come my regex grouping is not grouping correctly?

Tags: python, regex

Example of a line in the file: "CIS 14A Visual Basic .NET Programming I x   x   x   x"

I'm trying to group lines in a file into three groups: group(0) should be the course number (14A), group(1) should be the topic (Visual Basic .NET Programming I), and group(2) should be the quarters the course is available in. However, when I tested the code, group(0) matched the whole line, group(1) was the course #, group(2) was empty..., and group(3) was a combination of the topic and quarters available. I can't find what's wrong with it because each set of parenthesis creates a group but all the groups are in the wrong order and "CIS" which I have no included in any parenthesis was included in group(0) for some reason. I'm new to regex so any advice on how to fix my code would be much appreciated.

```
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            self._match = (re.search('^CIS\s(\d*\w*)(\w*)\s?[^x]*(.*)$', line, re.I))
            self._numb = self._match.group(0).strip()
            self._name = self._match.group(1).strip()
            self._quarter=self._match.group(2).strip().split('x')
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Try `^CIS\s+([0-9A-Z]+)\s(.*?)\s(x\s.*)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/QZu1sX/2

Comment: group(0) is always the full match. then your "parenthesised groups" start from 1

Comment: @TomerKalish Ah I see that was a good piece of information to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note there are always as many `.group()`s as there are capturing groups + 1 as the zeroth group is reserved for the entire match.

The regex you may use is

```
^CIS\s+([0-9A-Z]+)\s(.*?)\s(x\s.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JwGvYo/1/)

See Python snippet:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        self._match = re.search(r'^CIS\s+([0-9A-Z]+)\s(.*?)\s(x\s.*)', line, re.I)
        if self._match:
            self._numb = self._match.group(1).strip()
            self._name = self._match.group(2).strip()
            self._quarter=self._match.group(3).strip().split('x')
```

**Regex details**

- `^` - Start of string
- `CIS` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([0-9A-Z]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits or uppercase letters
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s` - whitespace
- `(x\s.*)` - Group 3: `x`, whitespace and any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Also, check the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5ECIS%5Cs%2B(%5B0-9A-Z%5D%2B)%5Cs(.*%3F)%5Cs(x%5Cs.*)):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow amazing website! I'm using alot of regex and never knew about that. Upvote for that :) One remark: depending on the exact format, but seems like group 1 should be ([0-9]+[A-Z]+)

Comment: Wow i'm going to need to study up on regex a lot more haha. I'm getting an error in my code now saying: builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @drewster you should read a bit the documentation. In general when re.search finds the pattern a Match object is returned. When no match found, None is returned. And this is why you get this error

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks for giving me the regex syntax!